# How can I sort students by first and last name while ignoring apostrophe in their name?

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, sorting

I'm trying to sort names while ignoring apostrophes. Right now I'm using Javascript and querying a mongo database with mongodb. In the query I use a `$sort` on the students by `lastName`, `firstName`. However when the names are returned, students with a `'` in their name come before those without. For example:

```
ex: (random, unsorted) 
D'Marcus O'Connell
Damian O'Connell
Damian O'Claire
Dylan Oliver
```

Here, `D'Marcus O'Connell` would come before `Damian O'Connell` per my `$sort`. However the client is using a separate grade book service from their legacy system to import rosters, and on their lists, they would ignore the `'` and instead `Damian O'Connell` would come before `D'Marcus O'Connell` because `a` precedes `m` in the alphabet. (I guess also ignoring capital letters with different char vals?)

Below is the data I've got to work with coming from the query. Right now I have excessive arrays just in case it may be useful. Initially I figured I'd try a sorting loop on last name, and if last name is equal, check first name... but I can't figure out how to strip the `'` mid sort or pre-sort. (Here, `Archie` and `Glenn` are two separate names I'm using as test subjects for sorting, which is why they are hard coded)

```js
var sortNamesArr = [];
var studentObjTemp = {};
var lastNamesArr = [];
var firstNamesArr = [];
for (i = 0; i < response[0].gridData.length; i++) {
    var lastName = response[0].gridData[i].lastName;
    var firstName = response[0].gridData[i].firstName;
    if (firstName == "Archie") {
        firstName = "A'rchie";
    }
    if (lastName == "Glenn") {
        lastName = "G'lenn";
    }
    studentObjTemp = {lastName, firstName};
    sortNamesArr.push(studentObjTemp);
    lastNamesArr.push(response[0].gridData[i].lastName);
    firstNamesArr.push(response[0].gridData[i].firstName);
}
```

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated. If at the very least you could point me in the right direction. I've seen other posts with regex stripping the apostrophe, but they don't seem to work for me.

edit: Here's an example of the sortNamesArr after returning a set of grid data with the student's names included -

```html
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {lastName: "Bowser", firstName: "Arnoldo"}
1: {lastName: "Coffey", firstName: "Abel"}
2: {lastName: "Dahl", firstName: "Alexis"}
3: {lastName: "Doyle", firstName: "A'rchie"}
4: {lastName: "Esquivel", firstName: "Bernadine"}
5: {lastName: "Fuller", firstName: "Ariel"}
6: {lastName: "G'lenn", firstName: "Anastasia"}
7: {lastName: "Nava", firstName: "Adrianne"}
8: {lastName: "Perry", firstName: "Alberta"}
9: {lastName: "Vera", firstName: "Anthony"}
```

Comment: Do you want to strip the `'`s so the stored data changes or do you only want to ignore them for the purpose of sorting?

Comment: @B-Schmidt only for the purpose of sorting. They have to retain the ' in the name afterward

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localeCompare` with `ignorePunctuation` option to sort ignoring punctuation.

```js
const names = [{lastName: "Bowser", firstName: "Arnoldo"}, {lastName: "Coffey", firstName: "Abel"}, {lastName: "Dahl", firstName: "Alexis"}, {lastName: "Doyle", firstName: "A'rchie"}, {lastName: "Esquivel", firstName: "Bernadine"}, {lastName: "Fuller", firstName: "Ariel"},{lastName: "G'lenn", firstName: "Anastasia"}, {lastName: "Nava", firstName: "Adrianne"}, {lastName: "Perry", firstName: "Alberta"}, {lastName: "Vera", firstName: "Anthony"}];
names.sort((a, b) => a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName, undefined, {ignorePunctuation: true }) || a.lastName.localeCompare(b.lastName, undefined, { ignorePunctuation: true }));
console.log(names);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Will this sort of thing also work on my current example where lastName and firstName are separated values? I could always concat them into one string and then split again, but I would assume that would mess with alphabetization, unless I'm mistaken.



edit: I should clarify -- last name is the primary sort, and then first name is secondary. So first it sorts based on lastName, and then if lastName is equal, it sorts on firstName. Though I like the idea of this localeCompare, I'll try it out!

Comment: Yes, it will sort on multiple fields. Can you share some data?

Comment: Yes, I'll add in an example of what would be returned above in an edit to my post (can't really format here in the comments)

Comment: The specific question that I received on it that began this request was on sorting the last names O'Neal and Oliver. In their legacy grade book it would show as Oliver, Brady; then O'Neal Stephen. As opposed to O'Neal then Oliver.

Comment: @AliveSquare I have updated the answer. It will first sort by `firstName` and `lastName`.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your sort callback in javascript, so it will be something like this

```
const names = [
  {firstName: "D'Marcus", lastName: "O'Connell"},
  {firstName: "Damian", lastName: "O'Connell"},
  {firstName: "Damian", lastName: "O'Claire"}
]

names.sort((a,b) => {
    var auxA = a.firstName.split("'")
    var auxB = b.firstName.split("'");
    if(auxA.join('').toUpperCase() > auxB.join('').toUpperCase()) return 1;
    else if(auxA.join('').toUpperCase() < auxB.join('').toUpperCase())  return -1;
    else {
      auxA = a.lastName.split("'")
      auxB = b.lastName.split("'");
      if(auxA.join('').toUpperCase() > auxB.join('').toUpperCase()) return 1;
      else if (auxA.join('').toUpperCase() < auxB.join('').toUpperCase()) return -1;
    }
  }
)
```

```
console.log(names)
[
  { firstName: 'Damian', lastName: "O'Claire" },
  { firstName: 'Damian', lastName: "O'Connell" },
  { firstName: "D'Marcus", lastName: "O'Connell" }
]
```

We split the `firstName` where there is a *'* and save in some auxiliary variable, then we compare these two variables with `join()` and `toUpperCase()` check which one is greater than the other and return that value, if they're equal, I do the same thing to the `lastName`. This will return your array sorted. Note: the "  ' " still will be there in the `response[0].gridData`.

Comment: Would I implement this then as an array of objects? sortNamesArr = [ {lastName1, firstName1}, {lastName2, firstName2}, etc... ]. => sortNamesArr.sort... and utilize your above logic?

Comment: Yes, implement an array of objects. In your example you have an array of objects that contain two properties `firstName` and `lastName`, so I made a sort function that considers that.

Comment: As you were saying that your problem is to sort `lastName` first, you just need to change the orders in my example, in my example it's sorting comparing `firstName` firsts.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for the comment. I was a little confused how the auxA join was still working to combine back into string but now I've got it. Thanks for the help